# Rails ActiveStorage and AWS compressing image on upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, rails-activestorage

I am using **ActiveStorage** and **aws-sdk-s3** to upload images to AWS. Currently i am using **mini_magick** gem to serve images in views by using something like

`image.variant(resize: '700x300')`

which resizes images to 700x300 pixels.

I want to compress image when uploading say the initial image is 4MB, i want to compress it to something like 250kb and upload like how other websites are doing. As uploading the full size takes up AWS space and increase storage costs. How can i achieve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by pre-processing the image before storing it using ActiveStorage. You can do so by using [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php).

However, due to how AWS pricing works, I'd say that storage is a minimum issue, you can find the pricing [here](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/). As you can see there, 1GB is not even 3 cents of a dollar, most likely you'll be having higher costs due to transfers which will happen frequently, however you can just "transfer" lower resolution images if you want to save money, and never really show the "original" file.

Comment: What do you mean by transactions in this case?

Comment: Transmitted data. Every time a user requests the image, Amazon charges you

Comment: @Waclock Can you provide an example of transferring lower resolution images?

Comment: @Nick I think **Waclock** refers to calling **.variant** so a lower resolution will always get transferred. I am not sure though.